# SeleniumWebdriver + C#

Tags: c#, selenium

1)Open site from google

```
 1.1 Open google.com
 1.2 Type in the input for search “белорусская железная дорога”
 1.3 Click on "Google Search" button
 1.4 From search results, click ling that corresponds to the target URL
```

[image]

2)Work with main page

```
 2.1 Open site
 2.2 Switch to the English language
 2.3 Check, that not less than 4 new are displayed in the "News" section
 2.4 From search results, click ling that corresponds to the target URL
 2.5 Check, that text “© 2019 Belarusian Railway” is displayed in the bottom of the page
 2.6 Check, that 5 buttons are present in the top part of the page: “Press Center”, “Timetable”, “Passenger Services”, “Freight”, “Corporate”
```

Work with search

Open site

- Type in “Поиск” input 20 random symbols (they should be different for each execution).
- Check, that address in browser changed to the https://www.rw.by/search/?s=Y&q=
- Check, that text “К сожалению, на ваш поисковый запрос ничего не найдено.” is displayed on a page
- Clear entered on step b value from the corresponding input, and enter “Санкт-Петербург” instead
- Click "Найти"
- check, that 15 links to the articles are displayed on a screen
- Write into the console text from that links

Work with calendar

- Open site
- Type in "Откуда" and "Куда" some valid locations' names
- Click on calendar button, and select date == 5 days from today, date should be selected even in case it is last day of the month e.g. in case you are running your test on 29th of September, it should select 4th of October, etc.
- Click on "Найти"
- Write to the console departure time and trains name in following format:

“Минск-Пассажирский — Брест-Центральный” – 19:25

- click on the first link
- Check that name of train is displayed on a page
- Check that text under the text "Дни курсирования" is not empty
- return to the main page of site by clicking on the site's logo
- check that main page loaded fine

I managed to accomplish only 3 subtasks in the first list
here is the code:

```
public class Tests
{
    private IWebDriver driver;
    private readonly By _inputField = By.XPath("//input[@name = 'q']");
    private readonly By _searchButton = By.XPath("//input[@class = 'gNO89b']");
    private readonly By _targetLink = By.XPath("//h3[@class = 'LC20lb DKV0Md']");
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var inputField = driver.FindElement(_inputField);
        inputField.SendKeys("белорусская железная дорога");
        var searchBtn = driver.FindElement(_searchButton);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        searchBtn.Click();
        var targetUrl = driver.FindElement(_targetLink);
        targetUrl.Click();
        Assert.Pass();
    }
}
```

I'm looking for useful resources related to this topic and help if possible with this task because i have 0 experience with selenium web driver

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.