# Selenium webdriver + C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I tried to ask question and i was asked to be specific so here I'll try to be specific as much as possible.
1)Check that not less than 4 news are displayed into the news section[image]

-Check, that text “© 2019 Belarusian Railway” is displayed at the
bottom of the page

- Check, that 5 buttons are present in the top part of the page: “Press
  Center”, “Timetable”, “Passenger Services”, “Freight”, “Corporate”
  here I tried to use location property with X and Y coordinates but
  after I asked question to my mentor he said I won't be able to
  determine it with this approach, so I have no idea how to check where
  element is located
- Type in “Поиск” input 20 random symbols (they should be different
  for each execution). I know about sendKeys method but how do I make
  my input random for each run
- Check, that address in browser changed to the
  https://www.rw.by/search/?s=Y&q=
- Check, that text “К сожалению, на ваш поисковый запрос ничего не
  найдено.” is displayed on a page
- Clear entered random value from corresponding input, and enter
  "Санкт-Петербург" instead
- click the find button. I know how to do this step
- Chech, that 15 links to the articles are displayed on the screen. No
  idea how to do this
- Write into the console text from that links
- Here is the code for the tasks i managed to complete

  ```
   [Test]
   public void Test1()
   {
       var inputField = driver.FindElement(_inputField);
       inputField.SendKeys("белорусская железная дорога");
       var searchBtn = driver.FindElement(_searchButton);
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
       searchBtn.Click();
       var targetUrl = driver.FindElement(_targetLink);
       targetUrl.Click();
       Assert.Pass();
   }
  ```

  }

Comment: What new info is here, that you could not add (using [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69620305/edit)), to your previous question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69620305/seleniumwebdriver-c-sharp  ?

Comment: I tried to make it more clear for people

Comment: You could/SHOULD do that with your original question. Duplicate, unanswered, questions are not good for anyone...

Comment: Should i delete this question in order to clean up?

Comment: I honestly have no  idea how to make my question more clear for people to get the answer or useful tips

Comment: I'm trying to google on my own but can't find a thing I even tried to look in documentation but couldn't find what could help me to solve this task, may I ask your help since you're the only one who I'm able to reach?

Comment: Maybe i forgot to specify that we have to determine that element is displayed at the footer or somewhere else, and I don't know how to do this I tried to use Location property with X and Y coordinates but my mentor said it won't work

Comment: managed to find series on youtube but still can't find how to determine if element is located in footer area
https://youtu.be/ixU48w5PeGo?list=PLUY1lsOTtPeIrejCf8okrn86lZSFo4yUD

Comment: @Luuk may I ask your help in this journey?

Comment: Try to ask the correct question to your mentor. He/She should, when asked the correct questions, be of help.

Comment: @Luuk yes they should but it doesn't mean they will, actually it means they won't give me the answer even in case when I'm in despair and none of my ideas worked, that is how it works in eastern europe